# Product attributes assigned to product, but not displaying on frontend when filtered in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, attributes

The issue is i have assigned an attribute to a product , but it is not filterable on frontend.
For e.g i have assigned this attribute value https://prnt.sc/srkv28e to a product. However, on front end it shows no matching products found https://prnt.sc/srkw6d.
What is the issue. What is the setting i need to do in backend?

Comment: Please check with reindexing.

Comment: i did that multiple times. did not affect anything

Comment: Let me tell you. this happened after i did migration from magento 1 to magento 2

Answer (score 0):

Please check the attribute setting in the manage attribute page(Store->Attributes). Attributes set with Filterable(With Results) only will have filter option in the front end.
Check the **Use in Layered Navigation** Option

[image]

Comment: I checked everything is perfect

Comment: @Nafisa I misread your question(first screenshot is missing). So your product assigned to this attribute is not showing in the frontend.Also please make sure this is appearing with other ways like direct view, and in listing?

Comment: No. in no way it is appearing

Comment: @Nafisa Then you need to debug that first. Check the product has all the necessary details , like website id, enable/disable status, visibility etc..